# WPF How can i get information about changing one View Model from another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have Main Window in which the content control and two Radio Buttnons are loceted.
MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel >
    <RadioButton Content="First"
                 IsChecked="True"
                 Command="{Binding FirstViewCommand}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Second" 
                 Command="{Binding SecondViewCommand}"/>
 </StackPanel> 

 <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Grid>
```

To this content control I bind my User Control.Here i have Combobox Listbox and Button. Based on Cobobox.SelectedElement I need to change data in ListBox after button have been pressed.
User Control:

```
<Grid>
<ComboBox x:Name="BoxOfDetails"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsScheme}">
</ComboBox>

<Button Command="{Binding ProduceCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BoxOfDetails, Path=SelectedItem}" />
<ListBox x:Name="ListOfMaterials"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" >
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I have also Main View Model which is data context to  Main window :

```
class MainVM : ObservableObject
  {
      public RelayCommand FirstViewCommand { get; set; } 
      public RelayCommand SecondViewCommand { get; set; }

      public FirstVM FirstViewModel { get; set; } 
      public SecondVM SecondViewModel { get; set; }
      private object _currentView;

      public object CurrentView
      {
          get { return _currentView; }
          set => Set(ref _currentView, value);
      }
      public MainVM()
      {
          FirstViewModel = new FirstVM();
          SecondViewModel = new SecondVM();
          CurrentView = FirstViewModel;

          FirstViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
          {
              CurrentView = FirstViewModel;
          });
          SecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
          {
              CurrentView = SecondViewModel;
    
          });
}
```

and View Model for my User Control:

```
 class FirstVM : ObservableObject
 {
 private ObservableCollection<DetailScheme> _detailsScheme;
 private ObservableCollection<Material> _materials;
 
 public ObservableCollection<DetailScheme> DetailsScheme
     {
 get => _detailsScheme;
 
 public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials
     {
 get => _materials;
 set => Set(ref _materials, value);
     }
 public RelayCommand ProduceCommand { get; set; }
 
 public FirstVM () 
     {
 _detailsScheme = GetDetailsScheme("D:/ DetailsScheme.json");
 _materials = GetMaterials("D:/ Materials.json");
 ProduceCommand = new RelayCommand(o => 
     {***});
 }
```

I need to save information in my ListBox when my user controls switching (for exmaple user selects something in the box and presses a button and data in listbox is updating now after switching contols I have the same inforamtion as it was when i started application)

I added method which saves information to file in my  user control View model :

```
public void SaveFirstVM() 
{
    SaveDetails(_details, "D:/ Details.json");
    SaveMaterials(_materials, "D:/ Materials.json");
}
```

I tried to call it when i switch views in Main ViewModel in command

```
SecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
          {
              CurrentView = SecondViewModel;
              FirstViewModel.SaveFirstVM()
          });
```

but nothing happens, i can call this save method after each press on produce button in UserControl View Model but i dont think that is a good way.
I added some breakpoints to my project and i can only suggest that the problem is that my UserControl View Model Create twice, first in MainVM and second time when initialize happens, and when i change data it happens in initialized object, and when i trying to save data from mainVM it saves other object that isnt changed

Comment: "*To this content control I bind my User Control.*" - what does that mean? Is there a DataTemplate that contains your UserControl? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: yes in my App. xaml there is  DataTempla(Datatype of VM) that contains my UserControl

Comment: Make sure the UserControl does not explicitly set its own DataContext. Also take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studion for possible data binding error messages when you debug the application.

Comment: ohh, ye my User control sets its own DataContext, idk that it will work without setting it,but i tried and suddenly it worked,thanks now everithing works
P.S. I thought that it wouldn’t work because the data is not displayed in the User Contorl constructor only in MainWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged your question with "MVVM", but you didn't implement it. In MVVM you have the *Model* that is responsible for data persistence. MVVM does not mean to cramp everything into the *View Model* classes. Having a *Model* with its *Model* classes should make the flow more obvious.

You could handle the `Frameworkelement.Unloaded` event to get notified about the current view being unloaded.
However, the graceful solution would be to manage page related persistence where you are already in full control of page management: your `MainVM` class.
Code should be cohesive and similar or related tasks should not be spread across the application.

`MainVM` is already able to precisely identify page switches without extra efforts. Since the `MainVM` should have a reference to one or more *Model* classes in order to fetch data which it will expose to the view e.g. by initializing the page view model classes, it also is able to call the relevant model classes for persistence.

Please note, that in proper clean OO programming you must care about type and type member accessibility (access modifiers like `public` or `private`). It's a very fundamental technique to make your code robust and APIs well defined.
Do not make everything `public`. Instead make everything `private` and change it to a less restrictive visibility e.g. `public` only when necessary. This also includes property accessors. For example, declare a `private set;` and public `get;`. Class internals must be only visible to the defining class or subclasses. See Data Hiding.

Your fixed/improved code including a proper MVVM structure and access modifier usage could look as follows:

**PageId.cs**

```cs
public enum PageId
{
  Default = 0,
  FirstPage,
  SecondPage,
}
```

**MainVM.cs**

```cs
public class MainVM : ObservableObject
{
  // Make code extensible by using a single navigation command 
  // which depends on the command parameter to identify the navigation target.
  public RelayCommand NextPageCommand { get; }

  // TODO::Choose a better name as the value is not a view, 
  // but a model for the view (e.g. CurrentViewData)
  private ObservableObject _currentView;
  public ObservableObject CurrentView
  {
    get => _currentView;
    private set => Set(ref _currentView, value);
  }

  // A Model reference
  private Repository Repository { get; }

  private Dictionary<PageId, ObservableObject> PageViewModels { get; }

  public MainVM()
  {
    this.PageViewModels = new Dictionary<PageId, ObservableObject>
    {
      { PageId.FirstPage, new FirstVM() },
      { PageId.SecondPage), new SecondVM() },
    };    

    this.NextPageCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteNextPageCommand);

    // Reference the model
    this.Repository = new Repository();

    // Initialize start page
    LoadPage(PageId.FirstPage);
  }
 
  private void ExecuteNextPageCommand(object commandParameter)
  { 
    if (commandParameter is not PageId pageId)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException($"Unexpected parameter type. ICommand.CommandParameter must be of type {typeof(PageId)}", nameof(commandParameter));
    }

    LoadPage(pageId);
  }

  private void LoadPage(PageId pageId)
  {
    ObservableObject oldPage = this.CurrentView;
    if (this.PageViewModels.TryGetValue(pageId, out ObservableObject pageViewModel))
    {
      this.CurrentView = pageViewModel;

      if (oldPage is not null)
      {
        SavePageData(oldPage);
      }
    }
  }

  /* Create overloads for individual page view model types */
  private void SavePageData(FirstVM pageViewModel)
  {
    // Delegate data persistence to the Model
    this.Repository.SaveDetails(pageViewModel.DetailsScheme);
    this.Repository.SaveMaterials(pageViewModel.Materials);
  }

  private void SavePageData(SecondVM pageViewModel)
  {
    // TODO::Delegate data persistence to the Model
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Use the `MainVM.NextPageCommand` as follows:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding NextPageCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Static local:PageId.FirstPage}" />
<Button Command="{Binding NextPageCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Static local:PageId.SecondPage}" />
```

The *Model* classes that implement the persistence details:

**Repository.cs**

```cs
public class Repository
{
  // Details about how persistence is implemented (file, database, web service etc.)
  // must be hidden from the View Model. 
  // Therefore, the Repository API must be kept simple.
  // Such details are encapsulated in a "low level" class,
  // in this case the type JsonRepository.
  private JsonRepository JsonRepository { get; }

  public Repository()
  {
    this.JsonRepository = new JsonRepository();
  }

  public void SaveMaterials(IEnumerable<Material> materials)
  {
    this.JsonRepository.SaveMaterials(materials);
  }

  public void SaveDetails(IEnumerable<DetailScheme> details)
  {
    this.JsonRepository.SaveDetails(details);
  }
}
```

**JsonRepository.cs**

```
internal class JsonRepository
{
  internal JsonRepository()
  {
  }

  internal void SaveMaterials(IEnumerable<Material> materials)
  {
    SaveMaterials(materials, "D:/Materials.json");
  }

  internal void SaveDetails(IEnumerable<DetailScheme> details)
  {
    SaveDetails(details, "D:/Details.json");
  }

  private void SaveMaterials(IEnumerable<Material> materials, string destinationPath) 
    => throw new NotImplementedException();

  private void SaveDetails(IEnumerable<DetailScheme> details, string destinationPath) 
    => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is a good example of how to implement MVVM but that is not solving my problem, i tried to execute simple version of this code  where  I tried to save data straight in SavePageData method like this:'private void SavePageData(FirstVM pageViewModel)
{
    Detail.SaveDetails(pageViewModel.Details, "D:/ Details.json");
    Material.SaveMaterials(pageViewModel.Materials, "D:/ Materials.json");
}'
but it has no effect, when i switch views data is not saving

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. This is not related to the example. It must be related to how you have implemented SavePageData. What you have posted in the comment looks really wrong. And it does not follow this example. When you switch pages then SavePageData is called. If it does not save any data, you are doing something wrong. Please update your question to add your current version. But first, try to follow this example. All you have to do is to replace the two NotImplementedExceptions in JsonRepository.cs with actual code that serializes the object to JSON.

Comment: I already solved my problem due to @Clemens the proplem was that i set data template in App.xaml and then I set it one more time in user control, so i think there was to copies of one object one was changing and other was not

Answer (score -1):

I use a class called an `ObservableHandler<T>` that lets me watch another class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and listens for `PropertyChanged` events.

If you were to use this you could watch for a property in the other ViewModel to change rather than having to save to a file.

### Usage

```cs
public class OtherViewModel
{
    private ObservableHandler<ViewModel> _handler;
    
    public OtherViewModel(ViewModel vm)
    {
        _handler = new ObservableHandler<ViewModel>(vm)
            .Add(v => v.Name, OnOtherNameChanged);
    }
    
    private void OnOtherNameChanged(ViewModel vm)
    {
        // react to the other property changing
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### ObservableHandler<T>

```cs
public class ObservableHandler<T> : IWeakEventListener
    where T : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly WeakReference<T> _source;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Action> _handlers = new();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<T>> _handlersT = new();

    public ObservableHandler(T source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        _source = new(source);
    }

    
    public ObservableHandler<T> Add(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Action handler)
    {
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));
        }

        var source = GetSource();
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Source has been garbage collected.");
        }

        var propertyName = GetPropertyNameFromLambda(expression);

        _handlers[propertyName] = handler;
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(source, this, propertyName);

        return this;
    }

    
    public ObservableHandler<T> Add(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Action<T> handler)
    {
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));
        }

        var source = GetSource();
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Source has been garbage collected.");
        }

        var propertyName = GetPropertyNameFromLambda(expression);

        _handlersT[propertyName] = handler;
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(source, this, propertyName);

        return this;
    }

    public ObservableHandler<T> AddAndInvoke(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Action handler)
    {
        Add(expression, handler);
        handler();
        return this;
    }

    public ObservableHandler<T> AddAndInvoke(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Action<T> handler)
    {
        Add(expression, handler);
        handler(GetSource());
        return this;
    }

    private T GetSource()
    {
        if (_source.TryGetTarget(out var source)) return source;

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(source)} has been garbage collected.");
    }

    bool IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return OnReceiveWeakEvent(managerType, sender, e);
    }

    public virtual bool OnReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (managerType != typeof(PropertyChangedEventManager))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var propertyName = ((PropertyChangedEventArgs)e).PropertyName;
        Notify(propertyName);

        return true;
    }

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        var source = GetSource();
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Confused, received a PropertyChanged event from a source that has been garbage collected.");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            foreach (var handler in _handlers.Values)
            {
                handler();
            }
            foreach (var handler in _handlersT.Values)
            {
                handler(source);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_handlers.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var handler))
                handler();

            if (_handlersT.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var handlerT))
                handlerT(source);
        }
    }

    public static string GetPropertyNameFromLambda(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
        MemberExpression memberExpression;

        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
        {
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property name lambda expression needs to be in the form: n = > n.PropertyName");

        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Bug, memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo cast failed.");

        return propertyInfo.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: to be honest do not really uderstand how this can be helpful in my case, first if i am not wrong now i need to pass VM parametr in constructor of other VM but i cant do it becouse other Vm is created first. Second i dont know how i need to react on data changing to save it when views are switching

Comment: You don't need to do it that way, it was just an example. You could create a static class to store the instance of the other ViewModel, inject it with some dependency injection framework ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)), use a [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger), or whatever else. There's a million ways to do it you don't have to explicitly pass it in. That's just what I do when one class needs to respond to changes in another.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/syntax-tm/SteamAchievementManager/blob/main/src/SAM.Core/API/Steamworks/SteamLibraryManager.cs) is an example of the `static` option. Wouldn't let me add it to the other comment because the text was too long.